# How to use ng-show without any html tag associated with it

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am in a situation where I need to show only the content without any html tag but as of my understanding i did not find anything without a html tag.

```
<span ng-show="expression">{{data}}</span>   //output <span>data</span>
```

But I want to show the text **without** the span tag

```
ng-show="expression" {{data}}   //output data
```

Answer (score 2):

The nature of HTML is that everything is contained in a tag of some kind, even if it's just the body tag.

The span tag is almost invisible anyway, so unless you have styled it to look differently, just use it.

The other option is to set the value of $scope.data to be blank in your code, then you don't need ng-show as such

Answer (score 1):

You can use an expression like the following: `{{ data ? data : ''}}`. If `data` is truthy it will print `data`. It's not pretty but it does work.

Comment: or: `{{ expression ? data : ''}}`

Answer (score 0):

As per angular [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) the usage for ng-show is element viz., ng-show is supposed to be used with any one html element.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without ng-show like so:

`{{ expression ? data : "" }}`